# Shape of a Winforms MessageBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I am looking for a way to have some control over the shape of a simple MessageBox in Winforms. I would like to control where the passed in text wraps so that the dialog rect is narrower. Windows seems to want to make the dialog as wide as possible before wrapping the text. Is there an easy way to control the maximum width of the dialog without resorting to creating my own custom form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can embed newlines in the text to force it to wrap at a certain point. e.g.

```
"message text...\nmore text..."
```

update: I posted that thinking it was a win32 API question, but I think the principle should still apply. I assume WinForms eventually calls MessageBox().

Comment: This should be Environment.Newline rather than \n

Comment: @Brann Or just "`\r\n`" as WinForms runs exclusively on Microsoft Windows, and Windows always uses `\r\n`. I think even the port of WinForms in Mono for Linux and macOS respects `\r\n`.

Answer (score 1):

There's really just two ways (sane ways)

1) Add line breaks to your string yourself to limit the lenghth of each line.

2) Make your own form and use it rather than messagebox.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you throw your own newlines in the string message you pass it? I'm pretty sure that will work if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102614/shape-of-a-winforms-messagebox#102622), or alternatively create your own form and use that.

Answer (score 0):

The \n newline chars will give you enough flexibility, then do this. I use this a lot. Eg. if I'm giving a warning, the first line will give the warning, and the next line will give the internal error message or further information as appropriate. If you don't do this, you end up with a very wide message box with very little height!

MessageBox only has limited variability - eg. the button types and icon. If you need more, then create your own. You could then do all sorts of things like add URLs, a Help button ,etc.